# Where can I get MUI language packs for Windows 10 build 10240?

Tags: windows

I can't find any language packs in Swedish for this build number. Do anyone know where to find it?

In Language Options it says:

```
A language pack isn't available
```

Comment: You can't.  Update to the current build of Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound: I would if I could. But I can't because of some software issues on some applications that do not run well on the latest build.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Swedish offline language pack offline using the [link](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/01/lp_3a84ba13cd849188f6b76ecf02e5528227449257.cab)

[Source:](http://winaero.com/blog/download-official-mui-language-packs-for-windows-10-build-9926/)

Other articles:

[1](https://www.itechtics.com/windows-10-language-packs-direct-download-links/)

[2](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win7)

[3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)